# Equals method override messes up other code/changes output?

Tags: java, oop, equals

I'm making a card game for a school project. I need my equals method to be able to correctly tell me if a card has the same rank as another card. However, I notice that as long as an equals override *exists*, even if I don't use ".equals()" on anything, it seems to screw up output for other code. Here is a sample of my output with the equals method active:

```
Player 1
Has spoon? false
Is dealer? true
Hand: [7 of Clubs, 2 of Clubs, 8 of Spades, 8 of Clubs]
Dealer: 
Your dealer has a deck of 48 cards: 

Cards currently in deck: 3 of Hearts, 4 of Hearts, 5 of Hearts, 6 of Hearts, 9 of Hearts, 10 of Hearts, Jack of Hearts, Queen of Hearts, King of Hearts, Ace of Hearts, 2 of Spades, 3 of Spades, 4 of Spades, 5 of Spades, 6 of Spades, 7 of Spades, 9 of Spades, 10 of Spades, Jack of Spades, Queen of Spades, King of Spades, Ace of Spades, 2 of Clubs, 3 of Clubs, 4 of Clubs, 5 of Clubs, 6 of Clubs, 7 of Clubs, 8 of Clubs, 9 of Clubs, 10 of Clubs, Jack of Clubs, Queen of Clubs, King of Clubs, Ace of Clubs, 2 of Diamonds, 3 of Diamonds, 4 of Diamonds, 5 of Diamonds, 6 of Diamonds, 7 of Diamonds, 8 of Diamonds, 9 of Diamonds, 10 of Diamonds, Jack of Diamonds, Queen of Diamonds, King of Diamonds, Ace of Diamonds
```

I can create multiple players and deal them each a set number of cards.

On some occasions players will get dealt duplicate cards, which is an obvious problem. On top of this, it doesn't remove the right cards from the deck, sometimes removing the right rank but the wrong suit. Notice that some cards in this player's hand are still in the deck but several Hearts cards are taken out.

This is output with the equals method commented out, nothing else changed:

```
Player 1
Has spoon? false
Is dealer? true
Hand: [7 of Diamonds, Queen of Hearts, 6 of Diamonds, King of Spades]
Dealer: 
Your dealer has a deck of 48 cards: 

Cards currently in deck: 2 of Hearts, 3 of Hearts, 4 of Hearts, 5 of Hearts, 6 of Hearts, 7 of Hearts, 8 of Hearts, 9 of Hearts, 10 of Hearts, Jack of Hearts, King of Hearts, Ace of Hearts, 2 of Spades, 3 of Spades, 4 of Spades, 5 of Spades, 6 of Spades, 7 of Spades, 8 of Spades, 9 of Spades, 10 of Spades, Jack of Spades, Queen of Spades, Ace of Spades, 2 of Clubs, 3 of Clubs, 4 of Clubs, 5 of Clubs, 6 of Clubs, 7 of Clubs, 8 of Clubs, 9 of Clubs, 10 of Clubs, Jack of Clubs, Queen of Clubs, King of Clubs, Ace of Clubs, 2 of Diamonds, 3 of Diamonds, 4 of Diamonds, 5 of Diamonds, 8 of Diamonds, 9 of Diamonds, 10 of Diamonds, Jack of Diamonds, Queen of Diamonds, King of Diamonds, Ace of Diamonds,
```

I am confident that this works perfectly. The player gets their specific cards and those cards are removed from the deck.

This is my equals method:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Card)){
            return false;
        } else {
            Card card = (Card) obj;
            return card.cardNum == this.cardNum;
        }
    }
```

I'm guessing this must be happening when the cards are removed from the deck, and not when they are created, because the deck is still made of 52 individual unique card objects even with the equals method.

So, I use 2 methods to remove a card from a deck: deal and deals

```
    /**
     * @return randomCard, the randomly selected card
     */
    public Card deal() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Card randomCard;

        randomCard = m_cards.get(rand.nextInt(m_cards.size()));
        m_cards.remove(randomCard);

        return randomCard;
    }
```

```
    /**
     * @param n, the number of times deal is called
     * @return cardsDealt, a LinkedList containing the cards removed from the Deck.
     */
    public LinkedList<Card> deals(int n) {
        LinkedList<Card> cardsDealt = new LinkedList<Card>();

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cardsDealt.add(m_deck.deal());
        }
        // System.out.print("\nRemoving: ");
        return cardsDealt;
    }
```

And this is the code I have for the Player class right now:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Player {
    private int playerNum;
    private boolean hasSpoon;
    private boolean isDealer;

    static Dealer dealer = new Dealer();
    LinkedList<Card> hand;

    public Player(int playerNum) {
        this.playerNum = playerNum;
        this.hasSpoon = false;
        if(this.playerNum == 1) {
            this.isDealer = true;
        }
        this.hand = new LinkedList<Card>(dealer.deals(4));
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "\nPlayer " + playerNum + 
               "\nHas spoon? " + hasSpoon + 
               "\nIs dealer? " + isDealer + 
               "\nHand: " + hand
              + "\nDealer: " + dealer;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player player1 = new Player(1);

        System.out.println(player1);
    }
}
```

Again, this is for school so don't give me the direct answer but I would appreciate to know why this is happening and be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: What's `cardNum`? You need to show your `Card` class.

Comment: Incidentally, always override `hashCode` when you override `equals` -- but that isn't causing any problem in this instance.

Comment: Oh: "I need my equals method to be able to correctly tell me if a card has the same rank as another card" If you consider that the Ace of Spades and the Ace of Clubs are the same Card, then your code is behaving as expected.

Comment: Because `equals` is used by `List.remove` to decide which item to remove.

Comment: Write another method on `Card`: `boolean hasSameRankAs(Card otherCard)` instead of breaking the semantics of `equals`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how `equals` affects other code:

```
public Card deal() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    Card randomCard;

    randomCard = m_cards.get(rand.nextInt(m_cards.size()));
    m_cards.remove(randomCard);

    return randomCard;
}
```

`m_cards.remove(randomCard)` – think how this method is going to know which card to remove from the collection? Exactly, it calls `equals` with the parameter and every item in the collection!

You have to decide: is a seven of hearts really *equal* to a seven of clubs? I don't think so. They might have the same rank, but for them to be considired equal, I'd expect them to have the same rank *and* the same suit.

The canonical implementation of this method is (more or less):

```
public boolean remove(final Object o) {
    final Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (Objects.equals(o, it.next())) {
            it.remove();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

PS Random instances should be reused, not recreated with `new` every time you need them. If you recreate, you are not getting good random values and might even end up with the same number several times in a row. To reuse, create it once in the constructor or store it in a `static final` field.